# error in xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

when i complie this file i got these error
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
R cannot be resolved to a variable

this is the android xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        />
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is main text"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        />

     <Button
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Tutorials"
         android:textSize="25px"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

/>
```

Comment: please see my answer and if this answer is helping you then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below XML file instead of your file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is main text"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tutorials"
        android:textSize="25px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```